# Implementing a Recomendation Engine in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, recommendation-engine

So, I want to implement a hybrid collaborative filtering algorithm, [(Full algorithm here)](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v75/v75-90.pdf).  The algorithm has a Ratings table

**Ratings:=(id, user_id, item_id, rating)**

this table basically records a users rating on an item. I have never implemented a recommender engine, but basically I want to calcualte:

- The Pearson Correlation coeficient between two users' commonly rated items [Formula and info can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient), [can also be seen here, page 501, marked as (1)](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v75/v75-90.pdf)
- Entropy, Hyper-entropy and Expected value [Formulas can be seen here on page 502, marked as (6)](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v75/v75-90.pdf)